# How to calculate number of quarters between two dates?

Tags: javascript, date

I am wondering if any of you knows how I can calculate number of quarters between two dates in javascript, having timestamps of two dates?

So far I get this:

```
var startDate = new Date(scope.start*1000).getTime();
var endDate = new Date(scope.end*1000).getTime();
var difference = Math.round((endDate-startDate)/(1000*60*60*24));
```

which gives me time elapsed between two dates.

Thanks!

Comment: What are the values for `scope.end` and `scope.start`?

Comment: I've updated the question. I was able to get time difference between two dates

Comment: What are the values for `scope.end` and `scope.start`? (2). Add examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Matt Johnson answered 2 years ago:

> There are three months in a quarter. So, this should work:

```
var beginDate = moment('2013 12 31');
var endDate = moment('2014 04 01');
Math.floor(endDate.diff(beginDate, 'months') / 3)
```

> However, realize
>   this will return the number of whole periods of 3 months each. This
>   may or may not align to the boundaries of a quarter that you are
>   thinking. For example, a period from March through May would be three
>   months but spans across two different quarters.

Comment: Did you and Rahul just copy some answer without its context?

Comment: var beginDate = moment('2013 12 31');
var endDate = moment('2016 02 09');

Comment: Works just great actually